# How can I order Chrome's history alphabetically?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

How can I order Chrome's history alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[History<sup>2</sup>](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp) can sort alphabetically, by last time of visit or by number of 
visits.

[image: History2 Chrome extension]

Comment: just installed it didn't need a restart.. it doesn't display anything when I search. or click "all history"

Comment: ok seems to work.. maybe it appears straight away but requires chrome restarting to show stuff.